# Function call repeating itself

Tags: javascript, dom-events, function-call

I've just started JavaScript and I am facing a problem. I've written a script in which I am calling a function. I don't know why this script is calling itself twice.

The code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var randomNo1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var randomNo2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

window.onload = ask;

function ask()
{
    alert("How much " + randomNo1 + " times " + randomNo2 + "?");
}

function question()
{
    var product = randomNo1 * randomNo2;
    var stdAnswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    
    if(stdAnswer == product)
    {
        alert("Very good!")
        //generate new nos
        randomNo1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        randomNo2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        ask();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No. Please try again.");
        ask();
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form>
Enter answer: <input type="text" id="answer" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="question()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please point-out if I am doing some mistake.

Comment: What do you mean "calling itself twice"? How does this manifest?

Comment: When clicking the button "Check" on form the function "ask()" is called for twice.

Comment: because ask is also called on windows.onload?

Comment: The `ask` function is only firing once for me: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/cBJmy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **action="#"** to your form, to avoid page being refreshed when form is submitted.

```
<form action="#">
Enter answer: <input type="text" id="answer" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="question()" />
</form>​
```

Comment: Ok I understood the problem caused by "submit" in this scenario. Thanks alot.

Comment: `action="#"` submits the form to itself, which results in the same phenomenon. The page is refreshed. You need to cancel the form submission instead.

Answer (score 1):

You call it twice, once at startup `window.onload = ask;` and once in `question`

[edit]
note too that you don't have a `;` after the first `alert()` in `question()`
[/edit]

Comment: I think "window.onload = ask;" will only call the function at the first loading only. Isn't it?

Comment: That missing semicolon is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Because your button is a submit button. When clicked it runs click handlers (if specified), then posts the form. So you call `ask()` twice. One time in a click handler, and another time in a `window.onload` handler.

After this form is submitted, page simply reloads (because it has no associated action). And `onload` handler is fired again.

You can see it here: http://jsbin.com/ukusof.

Answer (score 0):

Your form as no `method` nor `action`. When you click your `submit` button, the page refresh itself, thus firing `ask` again.

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the form, which loads the page again, so `ask` will be fired again on load.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `form` with a `submit` button. With no action in the form, it resubmits the page. You can stop this with

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="question();return false" />
```